# Convert multiple Images to varbinary in SQL Server from vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I just want to know the possible ways to convert like 2 or 3 images into a `varbinary` and save it in a single column named `images` in SQL Server. And retrieve it like the way to retrieve a single image.

Comment: We can help you but not likely going to find anybody who will write this for you. Try looking on google....there are hundreds and hundreds of examples of this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to store file data in the database, and the files are accessible to the SQL Server, then you can get SQL Server to do the heavy lifting using [`OPENROWSET`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx):

```sql
SELECT o.BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Myfilepath.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) o
```

SQL Server will return a single-column, single-row dataset that will contain the binary data for your file.

You can use the above statement stand-alone, in a stored procedure or as part of an `INSERT` statement.